# Invoking facebook sdk from a webview does not work if app is not installed?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Here's what I want in my android app.

I want a button in webview call a method in my java. This method should call facebook sdk's authorize() function and do SSO/Dialog way of authentication. The access token and the expire token are returned back to webview when i call a javascript method in webview.

Here's what I've created already.

In my onCreate() of activity I'm initializing the webview.

```
mFB = new Facebook(APP_ID);
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "JAVA");
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

The test.html in my assets folder is this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function authorizeFacebook() {
           JAVA.authorizeFacebook();    
        }

        function showData(token, expire) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = token + " >>>> " + expire;
        }
</script>
```

The interfacing between JS and Java are working fine. That I'm sure of. My JSInterface is -

```
public class JSInterface {
    public Context mContext;

    JSInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void authorizeFacebook() {   
        Log.e("FB", "authorizeFacebook() interface called");
        authorizeFacebookSSO();
    }
}
```

```
public void authorizeFacebookSSO() {
    mFB.authorize(FBCMTestActivity.this, new DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        Log.e("FBAUTH", "FB failed + " + e.getErrorCode());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FBFAIL:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        Log.e("FBAUTH", "FB failed + " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FBFAIL:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.e("FBAUTH", "SUCCESS");
        Log.e("FBAUTH:", mFB.getAccessToken() + " " + mFB.getAccessExpires());
        wv.loadUrl("javascript:showData( '" + mFB.getAccessToken() + "' , '" + mFB.getAccessExpires()  + "');");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
});
}
```

When I have the facebook app, this works great.

But when there is no facebook app, it should ideally show a Dialog with webview. But it fails and stops at - 'Loading...' screen.

[image]

It just stays there and doesn't even crash. There are no logs. After a while I get to either force close it or wait for it. Has anyone faced this issue before?

**UPDATE**

My onActivityResultCode() -

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mFB.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the `onActivityResult` method implemented in your activity? Can you post the activity code?

Comment: I've added the onActivityResultCode(). But my SSO is working fine. The Dialog is not. So does onActivityResultCode() matter?

Comment: Have you used a network sniffer to see what's the request sent and what's the response from facebook?

Comment: That was not required. I figured it out. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured this out myself.

When I call a Java function from WebView's javascript, the function runs in webview's thread. So making it run on UI thread fixed everything for me :)

Hope that helps others.

Here's the only change that I've made in the above code.

```
public class JSInterface {
    public Context mContext;

    JSInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void authorizeFacebook() {   

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
                try {
                        authorizeFacebookSSO();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });           
    }
}
```